# python 3.12 ERROR: Could not build wheels for aiohttp, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects

Tags: aiohttp

```
  error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.37.32822\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2
  [end of output]
```

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
ERROR: Failed building wheel for aiohttp
Failed to build aiohttp
ERROR: Could not build wheels for aiohttp, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects

many of python libraries neeed aiohttp but in python 3.12 it's can't be installed

Answer (score 0):

Looks like [aiohttp stable release doesn't support python 3.12](https://github.com/aio-libs/aiohttp/issues/7675) yet.

You can either try using the *beta* version `pip install 'aiohttp<4' --pre --upgrade` or use an older version of python such as 3.10 or 3.11.

Answer (score 0):

For python 3.12 you can try:

```
pip install aiohttp==3.9.0b0
```